# I'm using python to webscrape all the "a" tags on a website. And in the "a" tag I want to pick some words and store them

Tags: python, web-scraping

The link tag "a" has following text : "Mino Games (YC W11) Is Hiring Senior Engineers in Montreal, QC (workable.com)"

I want to store the "Mino Games" , "Senior Engineer"  , "Montreal" and "workable.com" in sqlite3.

Please suggest, how can I do it.

Comment: Are you sure that it always follows the same format as `something` **Is Hiring** `something` **in** `something` **,** `something` ?

Comment: looks like you've forgotten to include the website address your trying to scrape!!

Comment: This is the website link : https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs?next=19916090

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're scraping https://news.ycombinator.com/jobs, this this should work:

```
import re, sqlite3

conn = sqlite3.connect('jobs.db')
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute('''CREATE TABLE jobs
         (company text, position text, location text, source real)''')

company_pattern = re.compile(r'(.+)(hiring|looking|wants|is )', re.IGNORECASE)
source_pattern = re.compile(r'\(([^)]+)\)$')
location_pattern = re.compile(r'in (.*)|(remote)', re.IGNORECASE)
position_pattern = re.compile(r'(?:hiring|looking|wants) (.*)', re.IGNORECASE)
clean_up_pattern = re.compile(r'\(([^)]+)\)| is | for | in |a ', re.IGNORECASE)

# Load up <a> nodes into elements here

for element in elements:
    element = element.text
    source = source_pattern.findall(element)[0].strip()
    element = element.replace('(' + source + ')', '')
    company = clean_up_pattern.sub('', company_pattern.findall(element)[0][0])
    try:
        location = location_pattern.findall(element)[0][0].strip()
    except IndexError:
        location = 'Not stated'
    element = element.replace(location, '')
    position = clean_up_pattern.sub('', position_pattern.findall(element)[0])

    c.execute("INSERT INTO jobs VALUES (company, position, location, source)")

conn.commit()
conn.close()
```

This will parse around 80% of the job offerings there. Tweak the regular expressions if you need to capture more.

Comment: Thank you for the help, actually I'm a beginner in python, can you tell me how I load up the nodes of "a" tag. I'm using

 for item in soup.select('.storylink'):
   elements = item